# Setting xmin and xmax values for ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data I'm trying to add to my ggplot at brackets using geom_bracket.

I am using stats calculated using my model: `lsmeanstest <- lsmeans(d.lme, pairwise~Group*Sex*CS.NCS, adjust="tukey")` So I've had to create my own stats tables, ending up with a usable dataframe

```
    femalestats.test3 <- data.frame(c.d.Sex., yposition, group1, group2, p.value, asterisk)
femalestats.test3
  c.d.Sex. yposition  group1 group2             p.value asterisk
1   Female      1100  CS_Con CS_PNS   0.116919692069019     <NA>
2   Female      1100 NCS_PNS CS_Con 0.00342233667164871        *
3   Female      1100 NCS_PNS CS_PNS   0.652132067515967     <NA>
>
```

So, to get rid of the NAs I do `femalestats.test3omit <- na.omit(femalestats.test3)`
and get:

```
femalestats.test3omit
  c.d.Sex. yposition  group1 group2             p.value asterisk
2   Female      1100 NCS_PNS CS_Con 0.00342233667164871        *
```

If I use

```
p1 + geom_bracket(xmin = group1, xmax = group2, label = paste(femalestats.test3$asterisk),
  data = femalestats.test3, y.position = 900, step.increase = 0.1)
```

Works well, but I get brackets with NA values cluttering up the plot.

But using the NA omitted table:

```
p1 + geom_bracket(xmin = group1, xmax = group2, label = paste(femalestats.test3omit$asterisk),
                  data = femalestats.test3omit, y.position = 900, step.increase = 0.1)
```

I get an error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `xmin`.
x Input `xmin` can't be recycled to size 1.
ℹ Input `xmin` is `<chr>`.
ℹ Input `xmin` must be size 1, not 3.
```

I have no idea how to get around this.

Cheers!

If you need more info let me know!

```
p1 <- ggplot(corttestunitedmutated2, aes(x = Treatment_Status, y = mean)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Treatment_Status),
           colour = "black",
           stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),
                width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(.~c.d.Sex.,
             scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background  = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                     panel.border = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(title = "Corticosterone",
       y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)",
       x = "Status\nTreatment") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours,
                    labels=c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress"))

dput(corttestunitedmutated2)
structure(list(Treatment_Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("NCS_Con", "NCS_PNS", "CS_Con", "CS_PNS"
), class = "factor"), c.d.Sex. = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), N = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L), mean = c(793.185103222222, 415.2964824, 
491.711204444444, 337.354349777778, 828.866709611111, 470.6272386, 
617.146221777778, 521.39674985), sd = c(139.479678927179, 183.047203537505, 
115.471138211954, 78.2702347304746, 176.119561017744, 132.014450160878, 
167.489275167574, 181.880434256998), se = c(46.4932263090596, 
57.8846082502948, 38.4903794039847, 26.0900782434915, 58.7065203392481, 
41.7466346563155, 55.8297583891913, 57.5156434072629)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use to make `p1`? And which package do you use for `geom_bracket()` it's not part of ggplot2

Comment: added to question! `geom_bracket ()` is ggpubr

Comment: Your `geom_bracket()` code doesn't seem to work properly. Please can you run your code in a fresh R session and ensure it's fully reproducible?

Comment: hi @stlba I restarted R and I'm still getting the same error message for the `femalestats.test3omit` data.

Comment: Using only the code you've posted here? Using your code I get an error saying, "object group1 not found". Please can you post your entire code as one reproducible example that can be run in order alone (including creating `femalestats.test3` from scratch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having helped me figure out your issue. When you make your `femalestats.test3` table, you're creating vectors named `group1`, `group2` etc. and combining them into a dataframe, as here:

`femalestats.test3 <- data.frame(c.d.Sex., yposition, group1, group2, p.value, asterisk)`

When you use `geom_bracket(xmin = group1, xmax = group2, ...)`, it isn't using the data from `femalestats.test3$group1` and `femalestats.test3$group2`, but the data from the `group1` and `group2` vectors you created inititally. (This is why I had a different error to you as I didn't have these vectors).

It works okay for `femalestats.test3` as these vectors are identical to the columns. But when using `femalestats.test3omit` it stopped working as you now had a mismatch between the number of values, hence the error `Input` xmin `must be size 1, not 3.`

If you use this code instead, it should work as expected:

```
p1 + geom_bracket(xmin = femalestats.test3omit$group1, 
                  xmax = femalestats.test3omit$group2, 
                  label = paste(femalestats.test3omit$asterisk),
                  data = femalestats.test3omit,
                  y.position = 900, 
                  step.increase = 0.1)
```